# PANDAS - Difference between values in different rows and different column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, difference

I'd like to calculate the difference between an arrival and the following departure...
From:

```
Dep Arr
1 2
4 6
8 9
```

To

```
Dep Arr BreakAfter
1 2 2
4 6 2
8 9 Nan
```

...in a faster way than a for cycle.
Is there something like .diff() which can operate on different columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

This would work fine:

```
In [274]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[274]: 
   Dep  Arr
0    1    2
1    4    6
2    8    9

In [280]: df['Dep'].shift(-1) - df['Arr']                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[280]: 
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```